# Linq FirstOrDefault List inside a query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, firebird

I have this linq query

```
var numberGroups =
            from n in VISRUBs.Where(a => a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS <= d && a.VISANA.VISITE.PANUM == p)
            group n by n.RUBRIQUE into g

            select new { 
                
                RemainderCHAPLIB = g.Key.ANALYSE.CHAPITRE.LIBELLE,
                RemainderLIB = g.Key.LIBELLE,
                
                RemainderRUNUM = g.Key.RUNUM,
                vals = from vlist in g.OrderByDescending(a=>a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS)
                select vlist.VALEUR
                };
```

which gives me this result in Linqpad
[image: LinqPadResult]

What I want is to select the first and second item from the last field (**vals**) which is a `List<string>`.

I have tried this:

```
                var numberGroups =
            from n in VISRUBs.Where(a => a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS <= d && a.VISANA.VISITE.PANUM == p)
            group n by n.RUBRIQUE into g

            select new { 
                
                RemainderCHAPLIB = g.Key.ANALYSE.CHAPITRE.LIBELLE,
                RemainderLIB = g.Key.LIBELLE,
                
                RemainderRUNUM = g.Key.RUNUM,
                vals = from vlist in g.OrderByDescending(a =>               a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS)
                select vlist.VALEUR
                };
                                

            var lst = from  n in numberGroups
            select new 
            {
               RemainderCHAPLIB = n.RemainderCHAPLIB,
                RemainderLIB = n.RemainderLIB,
                
                RemainderRUNUM = n.RemainderRUNUM,
                VAL = n.vals.FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

but it didn't work, I got an exception:

> Dynamic SQL ErrorSQL error code = -104Token unknown - line 54, column 1OUTER

Answer (score 0):

found it !

```
    var lst = from  n in numberGroups.ToList()
            select new 
            {
               RemainderCHAPLIB = n.RemainderCHAPLIB,
                RemainderLIB = n.RemainderLIB,

                RemainderRUNUM = n.RemainderRUNUM,
                VAL = n.vals.FirstOrDefault(),
                ANT = n.vals.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```